# mantle.account.invoice.Invoice - How to correctly handle credit invoicing?

Tags: moqui

Let us assume there is a situation when I have an invoice from a supplier to my company (e.g. 1000 EUR). My company returns all the goods because of a problem. The supplier shall issue a credit invoice in amount of 1000 EUR, which I register in my system. As a result I will have (on behalf of the supplier) an account payable of 1000 EUR and an account receivable in the same amount. What is the preferred way of handling this situation, because there will be no money transferred, either way.

Should I generate a paymentApplication to both invoices? I want to see them as +1000 -1000 = 0 EUR.

Answer (score 0):

The current data model and services do not support applying an invoice to an invoice, i.e. canceling part or all of one invoice with another. That is something I have considered but IMO is messy... even if it is a common practice in certain parts of the world (from my limited knowledge of it an archaic practice that isn't so commonly used any more). That could be supported though, I have certainly considered it (adding an entity or perhaps modifying PaymentApplication to support it, adding a service to do it and a corresponding GL posting service to balance AP/AR accounts).

Right now the best thing to do a cancel the original invoice, which does the proper reverse GL postings if the invoice has already been posted.

If you want both invoices in the system and canceling entries somewhere the currently supported approach is to use a FinancialAccount, basically use FinancialAccount payments to pay both invoices and then the balance of the FinancialAccount represents the amount due or owed to the external party. There is full support for these sorts of FinancialAccount transactions, doing payments both ways (withdrawals and deposits), representing the liability for positive balances in the GL, etc.